# Linq to SQL Dynamic query on a custom table whose structure was modified at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am migrating an existing application that uses ADO.Net to .Net 4+ with Linq2SQL. The problem is that the application's database contains a table that is customized at runtime using a GUI designer, i.e. the table initially contains the primary key (Id) and 3 other columns, but then the user designs the data that will be tracked in the application using a GUI designer which in turn modifies the structure of this table adding the columns to accommodate the need. The designer also records the structure of this table in a meta-data table that describes these custom columns.

The current application builds SQL strings to build queries. How can I handle querying from this table using Linq2SQL? Is using `context.ExecuteQuery<>` the only way to do it?

Comment: You're probably better off just not, even if it's *possible*, it's going to be *much* harder than more traditional methods of database interop.  LINQ is specifically designed to work with schemas that are known at compile time, simply because that's the case for the vast majority of cases, and that was the exact case made harder by older querying mechanims.  When you actually require the dynamicism of those older mechanisms, use them.  LINQ is there to make the 98% of cases easier.  You're in the 2%.

Comment: You can implement different data access for the special cases. We use Dapper the micro ORM in our organization for those cases that can't be easily solved within LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use dynamic.cs to get what you are looking for. Might be better to use stored procedures and have the dynamic sql done in the sprocs. Here is the link to dynamic.cs with examples.

[dynamic.cs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)