# Best way to build a linq query based on user selection in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, telerik-grid

I am trying to build a site and I have database that I am accessing with linq.  The user is directed to the site and initially the query uses the id that is provided in the link to query the database.  Then there are some drop down combo boxes that can have multiple items selected.  On post back I need to use the checked items to query the database to return a new result based on the user selections.

I have tried creating a string with all the text from each selection and then using something similar to the following bit of code.

```
q = from db.database
Where StringOfValues.Contains(db.items)
```

The problem is it is not exact and returns extra items that the user would not want.  So what would be the best way to build the linq query if I never know how many values the user will choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a series of ifs.

```
var query = myBaseQuery();

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    query.Where(item => item.Name == name);
}
```

and so on.  As long as your query is still of type IQuerable you can add wheres, group by, order bys, and other linq methods.  Just check what values the user provided and add them to the base query.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is going to be dynamic, maybe LINQ is not the best way to retrieve the data and good old ADO.NET is a better approach, where you can build a normal SQL query dynamically.

If you do need to use LINQ I suggest looking into [Dynamic LINQ](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) library - it looks like it has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

there is a library you can download it does exactly what you are trying to do. It is basically all the the linq with lambda expressions that gets parsed by these extension methods. the link provided points to another answer that has the link to the source and examples.

[linked answer to dynamic.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711133/3084080)